# show error message below the input field and errorContainer

Tags: jquery

**JQuery Code :**

```
$(function() {
    var user_form = {
    rules : {
        name : "required",
        address : "required",
          .
          .
        year : {
            required : true,
            digits : true
     }
    },
    messages : {
        year{
            required : "Please provide a year",
    digits : "Only Enter Digits"
        }
    },
            errorContainer: $('#errors'),
    errorLabelContainer: '#errors',
    wrapper:'li',

        submitHandler : function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    };

    jQuery("#user-create-form").validate(user_form);
    jQuery("#user-edit-general-info").validate(user_form);
    });
```

When i click on submit button it works fine it shows errormessages in div id="errors

My problem is

1) i want to show error message at below the input field tag as well as in errors div

2) in errors div it shows the messages as "This field is required", i want to show with field details : name is required, address is required like that (using label of the input tag)

how i can proceed please any one help me?